# How came the coefficients of vectors in the Solution?

Tags: coordinate-systems, affine-geometry

Let  (A,a1,a2)  and  (B,b1,b2)  be  two  affine  coordinate  systems  (illustrated  below).Represent the point P in both systems.
As Solution is in the Image . I want to Know that how are these values calculated e.g 2 ,3 ,5/2 and 3/2.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4vtk.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI3EE.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4vtk.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let be $O$ the center of a rectangular coordinate system fixed at the bottom-left corner of the grid as shown in the image:

[image]

The components of vectors $\vec{OA},\ \vec{OB}, \ \vec{OP}, \ \vec{a_1}, \ \vec{a_2}, \ \vec{b_1}$ and $\vec{b_2}$:
$$
\vec{OA}=(2,1)
$$

$$
\vec{OB}=(10,2)
$$

$$
\vec{OP}=(6,3)
$$

$$
\vec{a_1}=(-1,1)
$$

$$
\vec{a_2}=(2,0)
$$

$$
\vec{b_1}=\vec{a_1}
$$

$$
\vec{b_2}=(-1,-1)
$$

The goal is to express vector $\vec{OP}$ as the following linear combinations:
$$
\vec{OP}=\vec{OA}+k_{1}\vec{a_1}+k_{2}\vec{a_2} \quad \textbf{[1]}
$$
$$
\vec{OP}=\vec{OB}+m_{1}\vec{b_1}+m_{2}\vec{b_2} \quad \textbf{[2]}
$$

From $\textbf{[1]}$, you get this linear system of equations:
$$
6=2-k_{1}+2k_{2}
$$

$$
3=1+k_{1}
$$

Whose solution is $k_{1}=2$ and $k_{2}=3$

From $\textbf{[2]}$:
$$
6=10-m_{1}-m_{2}
$$
$$
3=2+m_{1}-m_{2}
$$
You obtain $m_{1}=\frac{5}{2}$ and $m_{2}=\frac{3}{2}$